# Setting up a Raspberry Pi for Wi-Fi streaming video access from a kite outdoors

Tags: wireless-networking, video-streaming

I want to attach my already setup, video-streaming-capable Raspberry Pi web server setup to my kite and allow others in the close proximity to view the video via an IP address. There obviously won’t be any kind of commercial Wi-Fi  service available so I assume I will have to create my own.

I tried making this all work using only one Raspberry Pi, but I think I need to use another Raspberry Pi.

How can I accomplish this?